# Error on Handler.post Android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

i have this code to return the weather image but i have this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
>               at example.example.run(Logo.java:112)

this is the function on i have the error:

```
    private void updateWeatherData(final String city) {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    final JSONObject json = RemoteFetch.getJSON(getActivity(), city);
                    if (json == null) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        getActivity().getString(R.string.place_not_found),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
  error where ----->   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                renderWeather(json);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object
>   reference

Means `handler` is `null`.

Initialize `handler` object before calling `post` method :

```
handler=new Handler();
```

Comment: Thks a lot, and sorry for lost time.